# Magento - Output product's categories, but filter it to show only one category tree

Tags: php, magento, categories, product

Apologies if this has been asked already, but I've searched and searched but not found an answer specific enough to my needs.

Basically on my product panel I want to output all categories specific to that product, and I have done this using the following code:

```
$currentCatIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
$categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('name')
->addAttributeToSelect('url')
->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $currentCatIds)
->addIsActiveFilter();

 foreach($categoryCollection as $cat){ ?>
 <a href="<?php echo $cat->getUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $cat->getName(); ?>"><?php echo $cat->getName(); ?></a>
<?php }
```

However for my categories I am using a couple of different category structures to allow users to find products, one based on the product type, and one based on the industry the user is in. To explain my structure see an example below:

Root Category

1. Clothing

   - Jackets
   - Trousers
2. Industry

   - Construction
   - Agriculture

So in my product panel I only want to show the categories which are under the industry parent category, in my case category ID 8.

I've found options to show only the second level categories, but this will not work for me as a product could then show in jackets and construction for example and I only want those in the categories under the industry parent category to be displayed.

Can anyone help point my in the right direction?

Thanks